# Como aplicar o padrão Singleton corretamente?

Tags: java, design-pattern, singleton

A classe `PEHandlerService` precisa ter uma única instância e não quero utilizar `synchronized` por causa da lentidão, elaborei o seguinte código:

```
public class PEHandlerService extends PlanilhaHandler {
    private LanguageHandler languageHandler;
    private static PEHandlerService instancia = new PEHandlerService();

    private PEHandlerService() {
        this.languageHandler = new LanguageHandler();
    }

    public static PEHandlerService getInstancia() {
        return instancia;
    }
}
```

Recebo `java.lang.NullPointerException` depois que instancio e acesso os métodos, tentei instanciar `PEHandlerService` no construtor privado e ocorre o mesmo.

Só consigo quando modifico para:

```
public class PEHandlerService extends PlanilhaHandler {
    private LanguageHandler languageHandler;
    private static PEHandlerService instancia;

    private PEHandlerService() {
        this.languageHandler = new LanguageHandler();
    }

    public static PEHandlerService getInstancia() {
        if (instancia == null) {
            instancia = new PEHandlerService();
        }
        return instancia;
    }
}
```

Os dois códigos não deveriam retornar `instancia`? Por que isso só ocorre no código 2?

Comment: Apesar de que o mais comum é vermos a segunda forma, eu já fiz da primeira forma e funciona também. Na primeira forma a instância será criada quando a classe for inicializada e na segunda forma a instância será criada sob demanda (no primeiro consumo de *getInstancia*), e esta diferença do momento de inicialização é que deve estar confundindo algum código que não estamos vendo na pergunta (código consumidor ou o código da classe pai *PlanilhaHandler*). Experimente mostrar estes códigos também, bem como o stack trace completo da exceção.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sua primeira forma está "mais correta", isto é, sem teste no método `getInstance`. O livro *Effective Java* (Java Efetivo) já discutiu profundamente neste assunto há muitos anos.

Vamos ver alguns pontos abaixo...

## Singleton sem concorrência

A implementação do *singleton pattern* mais simples é desta forma:

```
private static PEHandlerService instancia;
public static PEHandlerService getInstancia() {
    if (instancia == null) instancia = new PEHandlerService();
    return instancia;
}
```

Como você já sabe, esta versão *poderia* gerar duas instâncias num cenário um tanto incomum, isto é, se duas *threads* executassem o `getInstance` ao mesmo tempo na primeira chamada ao método.

## Singleton concorrente

Para resolver isso, a solução mais fácil é sincronizar o método:

```
private static PEHandlerService instancia;
synchronized public static PEHandlerService getInstancia() {
    if (instancia == null) instancia = new PEHandlerService();
    return instancia;
}
```

Isso evita problemas de concorrências, mas gera um pequeno atraso em cada chamada ao método para gerenciar a concorrência, além do que se houverem múltiplas *threads* somente uma poderá chamar o método por vez, possivelmente gerando gargalos num sistema altamente concorrente.

## Singleton concorrente com sincronização mínima

Para melhorar um pouco a versão acima, alguns autores propõem a seguinte construção:

```
private volatile static PEHandlerService instancia;
public static PEHandlerService getInstancia() {
    if (instancia == null) {
        synchronized (PEHandlerService.class) {
            if (instancia == null) instancia = new PEHandlerService();
        }
    }
    return instancia;
}
```

Isso faz com que a sincronização ocorra somente na inicialização e não nas demais chamadas.

Porém, note o modificador `volatile` no atributo da classe. Ele é necessário mesmo com a sincronização, pois devido ao modelo de memória do Java, principalmente antes do Java 5, ainda poderiam ocorrer erros causados por um tipo de *cache* onde outras *thread* poderia ainda ver o valor `null` na variável, mesmo após a atribuição por outra *thread* de modo atômico.

## Cuidado com inicializações em múltiplos comandos

Um cuidado muito importante é não atribuir o objeto à variável estática antes dele estar completamente inicializado. Considere o seguinte código:

```
private volatile static PEHandlerService instancia;
public static PEHandlerService getInstancia() {
    if (instancia == null) {
        synchronized (PEHandlerService.class) {
            if (instancia == null) {
                instancia = new PEHandlerService();
                instancia.setAlgumaDependencia(new Dependencia());
            }
        }
    }
    return instancia;
}
```

O código acima atribui uma nova instância de `PEHandlerService` à `instancia` e depois passa algum objeto para ela. O problema é que como `instancia != null`, outra *thread* pode chamar o método `getInstancia` e recuperar o objeto antes dele receber a dependência. Neste caso você poderia ter um `NullPointerException`.

## Singleton pré-carregado sem sincronização

Para evitar todos esses problemas acima, a solução mais simples apontada é simplesmente inicializar o seu objeto *singleton* fora do método *getInstance*, exatamente como no seu primeiro exemplo:

```
private static PEHandlerService instancia = new PEHandlerService();
public static PEHandlerService getInstancia() {
    return instancia;
}
```

Se for necessário algum tipo de inicialização, é possível usar um bloco de inicialização estático:

```
private static PEHandlerService instancia;
static {
    instancia = new PEHandlerService();
    instancia.setDependencia(new Dependencia());
}
public static PEHandlerService getInstancia() {
    return instancia;
}
```

A maior diferença desta abordagem é que o objeto não será mais inicializado por demanda (*lazy initialization*), mas logo que a classe for usada pela primeira vez (*eager initialization*). Isso pode ser bom ou ruim, dependendo do caso.

## Singleton concorrente sem sincronização

Para tentar juntar tudo, isto é, evitar sincronização e carregar o *singleton* em modo *lazy*, existem algumas alternativas.

Uma delas consiste em usar uma terceira classe para carregar a variável estática somente quando a mesma for acessada. Exemplo:

```
private static class SingletonLoader {
     private static PEHandlerService instancia = new PEHandlerService();
}
public static PEHandlerService getInstancia() {
    return SingletonLoader.instancia;
}
```

## Alternativa: use um Enum

Outra alternativa ao Single é simplesmente declarar a sua classe como um Enum de um valor só. Exemplo:

```
public enum PEHandlerServiceSingleton {
    INSTANCE;

    //métodos aqui

}
```

E aí você pode acessar isso da seguinte forma:

```
PEHandlerServiceSingleton.INSTANCE
```

## Considerações

Existem muitas formas diferentes de usar um padrão como o Singleton. Cada uma pode ser boa ou ruim para determinadas situações e algumas escondem certos problemas.

Entretanto, um vez que se compreenda um pouco a diferença entre as implementações, não é difícil escolher uma que se encaixe melhor na sua solução.

Comment: Bacana a explanação completa. Uma pequena correção no texto: atributos estáticos não são inicializados quando a classe é carregada nem durante a inicialização do programa, e inicializadores estáticos também não são executados neste momento. Em vez disso, eles são inicializados durante a inicialização da classe, o que ocorre, grosseiramente falando, no primeiro uso dela.

Comment: @Caffé Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1):

Tente ver se o erro não está sendo causado em outro local. Pq seu segundo código parece estar correto.

Esta é a forma correta de se implementar um singleton:

```
//Crie uma variável private para armazenar a instancia
private static PEHandlerService instance;
public static PEHandlerService GetInstance(){
    //Verifica de instance é null. Caso seja, instancia PEHandlerService.
    if (instance == null)
         instance = new PEHandlerService();
    return instance; // retorna a instancia
}

//o resto do código
```

Qualquer dúvida é só falar.